# ReferenceError: "routes" is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code:

```
var vuelo=require('../flights'); 
var flights1= flight({  number:1,
origin: 'Venezuela',    destination: 'Canada' }); 

var flights2= flight({
    number:2,   
    origin: 'Colombia',
    destination: 'Argentina' 
});

exports.flights1=function(req, res) {
    res.json(flights1.getInformation()); 
};

exports.flights2=function(req,res) {
    res.json(flights2.getInformation()); 
};

module.exports = routes;
```

In line `module.exports = routes;`  I receive the following error:

`ReferenceError: "routes" is not defined  at Object.<anonymous>`

But I dont know what`s means this error and where I fail.

Comment: There isn't a `routes` object of any kind defined in the code you included.  Do you define `routes` someplace else in the same file?

Comment: Hello,  This piece of code belongs to  "index.js" file which is allocated in the routes folder.

Comment: ...and there still isn't a `routes` object in the code you posted.  In order to use `modules.export`, there has to be a `routes` to export in that file.

Comment: Don't be confused with which folders your files are, just comment out the `module.exports = routes;`, you are already exporting the methods flights1 and flights2.